# Changing the outline commands

Tags: sectioning, org-mode

I am using org-mode to manage both HTML and PDF versions of my notes. When it exports to LaTeX, it uses `\section`, `\subsection` etc. But the document class I use have `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection` as outlining commands. So I tried to make every `\section` into a `\chapter` and every `\subsection` into a `\section`. To achieve this, I tried following:

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\section}
\renewcommand{\section}{\chapter}
```

But here, subsection become section and since sections then become chapter, I am left with only chapters. How can I a achieve this behaviour? My document class is not supported well by org-mode so I am trying to tweak my output manually. That's why I am seeking a primarily LaTeX solution rather than scripting `org-mode` with Elisp.

Comment: Maybe try this: `\let\oldsection\section\renewcommand{\subsection}{\oldsection}\renewcommand{\section}{\chapter}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `\let` statements, in this order:

```
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter
```

After `\let\subsubsection\subsection` the former definition of `\subsubsection` is inaccessible; instead, `\subsubsection` and `\subsection` now both point to the definition of `\subsection`.

After `\let\subsection\section`, `\subsection` points to the definition of `\section`; the former definition of `\subsection` is still available via `\subsubsection` because of the previous `\let` statement.

Finally, after `\let\section\chapter`, `\section` points to the definition of `\chapter` (as `\chapter` continues to do, but you will not use this command); the former definition of `\section` is still available via `\subsection` because of the previous `\let` statement.